# Issue in parsing irregualr json format in android

Tags: android, json

I want to parse following JSON

```
{
"fail": true,
"errors": {
    "arrival_date": ["The arrival date should be greater than or equal to departure date !!!"]
   }
}
```

I want to get value of *The arrival date should be greater than or equal to departure date !!!*

I tried this code but not getting success

```
try {
    org.json.JSONObject jsonObj = new org.json.JSONObject(PostParseGet.mStringresponse);
    org.json.JSONObject   c = jsonObj.getJSONObject("errors");
    JSONArray contacts = c.getJSONArray("arrival_date");
    Log.d("Errors",contacts.get(0).toString());
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Any idea how can I get this value?

Comment: What is the error you have facing?

Comment: the code seems valid, are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: Droidman: no execption

Comment: Rohit5k2: no any error

Comment: Do you have any filter set in logcat? Probably thats why you can't see the log. Nothing wrong in you code.

Answer (score 2):

```
String data ="{ 'fail': 'true', 'errors': { 'arrival_date': ['The arrival date should be greater than or equal to departure date !!!']}}";
try {
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject error = object.getJSONObject("errors");
    JSONArray array = error.getJSONArray("arrival_date");
    String dataString  = array.getString(0);
    String dat = dataString;
}
catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below Code

```
try {
    JSONObject jObject=new JSONObject(PostParseGet.mStringresponse);

    JSONObject errorObject=jObject.optJSONObject("errors");
    JSONArray arraiValArray=errorObject.optJSONArray("arrival_date");

    if(arraiValArray.length()>0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < arraiValArray.length(); i++) {
            Log.i("TAG", "String:"+arraiValArray.optString(i));
        }
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: :) gr8 it helped you